# Websockets code error

Tags: react-native, websocket

I am starting out with websockets in React Native, following this article:

https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34

It's well written and should give me a good basis to start from if I can get it working. I think the code was created for React but hopefully it should work with React Native.

I have copied out the code for the 3 files and it runs without errors (both server and client) but the App.js client doesn't update, it just displays 'Timer value from the server: no timestamp yet'

I created the application with: **create-react-native-app socket-timer**

In the new directory I installed:  **npm i --save socket.io** and then **npm i --save socket.io-client**

My 3 files are:

server.js https://pastebin.com/zgp6pdjq

```
const io = require('socket.io')();

io.on('connection', (client) => {
  client.on('subscribeToTimer', (interval) => {
  console.log('client is subscribing to timer with interval ', interval);
setInterval(() => {
  client.emit('timer', new Date());
}, interval);
});
});

const port = 8000;
io.listen(port);
console.log('listening on port ', port);
```

api.js https://pastebin.com/aLiiyMU1

```
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

const  socket = openSocket('http://localhost:8000');

function subscribeToTimer(cb) {
  socket.on('timer', timestamp => cb(null, timestamp));
  socket.emit('subscribeToTimer', 1000);
}

export { subscribeToTimer };
```

App.js https://pastebin.com/vxfWEaPz

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { subscribeToTimer } from './api';

export default class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  subscribeToTimer((err, timestamp) => this.setState({ 
    timestamp 
  }));
}

state = {
  timestamp: 'no timestamp yet'
};

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Timer value from the server: {this.state.timestamp}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

I start the server in one console window with: **node server**
I start the client app in another console window with: **npm start** (and then launch it with Expo on the android device)

It would be great if you could check it out for me as I am not seeing any errors (I have checked that port 8000 is open on the PC firewall)

Answer (score 0):

It was this line in app.js :

**const socket = openSocket('localhost:8000');**

I changed it to the IP address of my laptop:

**const socket = openSocket('192.168.1.94:8000');**

To be honest I have no idea why it couldn't deal with localhost. I'm guessing it must have something to do with Expo.